# Javascript optimizing regex function to extract sentences from a string containing a keyword

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I currently have a function to take a string, break it up into sentences, then extract the sentences that contain a user defined keyword and return them:

```
function getSentencesWithWord(word, text) {
    let sentenceArray = text.replace(/([.])\s*(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|")
    return sentenceArray.filter(sentence => sentence.includes(word))
}
```

Currently, this function works.  However, the amount of text I need to search through with this function is quite large; it is searching through around 30 google docs that could each be up to 75 pages each, and searching for certain terms (such as the word "the") can take up to a minute for the function to complete.  Is there a more optimized way to search through and extract this much text?

**Edit:**

Because someone asked in the comments, the `word` variable is just a string obtained from a text input on an HTML page and the `text` variable is a string obtained via this function in a Google Apps Script:

```
function getText(docID){
    let doc = DocumentApp.openById(docID);
    let textToSearch = doc.getBody().getText();
    return textToSearch;
}
```

I have an array of all the google doc IDs I need to access and I just iterate over the array and obtain the text for each doc

Comment: Can you share how are the `word` and `text` var? How do you get and parse all those docs?

Comment: You could split directly on `/(?<=\.)\s*(?=[A-Z])/` instead of replacing this space with a pipe and then split on pipe, this is suppressing the replace command. It suppose you can use lookbehind that is not yet supported in all browsers.

Comment: @Kessy I updated the original post which explains this

Comment: Have you managed to solve you issue? If not is there anything else to add to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was unable to find a faster method of achieving this with Google Apps Script so I just went back to Node.js and ended up using the Google Drive API to download the files as .txt files, which are much smaller and so I can search through them much faster now

Answer (score 0):

The replace you've provided, `replace(/([.])\s*(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|")`, didn't work for me == got the same string without change...

How about this:

```
("|"+text.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "|")+"|").includes("|"+word.toLowerCase()+"|")
```

Or, this:

```
("|"+text.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("|")+"|").includes("|"+word.toLowerCase()+"|")
```

Comment: This replaces **all** the spaces with pipe! OP's regex breaks the text into individual sentences.

Comment: Yes, @Toto is correct; I need a block of text broken into individual sentences rather than all spaces replaced

Comment: I've tried again, it just returns a single item array consisting of the whole text.
`function getSentencesWithWord(word, text) {
    let sentenceArray = text.replace(/([.])\s*(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|")
    return sentenceArray.filter(sentence => sentence.includes(word))
}`.  `getSentencesWithWord("how", "hello world!  how are you?")` returns `["hello world!  how are you?"]`.

Comment: So yes this is working as intended, the original regex intentionally does not count any punctuation except for periods

Comment: Got it (finally...).  Well, if it ain't broke - why fix it?!?  You could go through the text, find the word, go back to find beginning of sentence and go forward to find end of sentence, cut and push to array...  Or, split by ends of sentences and search that array with includes.

Comment: So it does work yes but my issue is the processing time.  Like I said I'm searching through a LOT of text so often a search can take almost a minute which I feel is a little egregious

Comment: there is a way, that i don't know(...) to shoot the sentence to the html as soon as it's found, and keep looking in the background.  maybe custom event listener that you raise for each found sentence = the user doesn't fall asleep and sees that the site is alive.